# why mysql_query not working with defined variables

Tags: mysql

Why when I'm running this query in PHP file I'm getting nothing. Any suggestions.

And when I run the same code in SQL phpMyAdmin it works normally. I need help how do I need to edit my code to be able to run.

```
$sql = "SET @prev_value = NULL;";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $sql = "SET @rank_count = 0;";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $sql = "SELECT *, 
    CASE
    WHEN @prev_value = totalPoints THEN @rank_count
    WHEN @prev_value := totalPoints THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
    ELSE @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
    END AS userRank
    FROM resultsTestDB
    ORDER BY totalPoints;";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($data); $i++){
        if ($data[$i]['memberID']==$memberID)
            $myRank = $data[$i]['userRank'];
    }

    return $myRank;
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated and removed in php7 - change to mysqli_

Comment: check if multi_statement is enabled.. or create stored procedure and pass the args!

Comment: Changed, but no difference.

Comment: I already added mysqli and still returning anything only in phpMyadmin

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Actually MySql accepts multiple statements as long as you configure it to. Using `allowMultiQueries=yes` as a connection parameter.

Comment: How would it be with allowMultiQueries in mysql as connection parameter? As example  Thanks

Comment: Well, although mysql supports such configuration PHP does not. Accordingly to its [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php) see "Note" in Flags section. You will need to use [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to do so.

Comment: It's not necessary to use multi query. Just execute each SQL statement separately. As long as you use the same MySQL connection, the session variable will still be set.

Comment: I have tried like you and updated my answer, and now no errors but returning nothing.